# Obtaining a sequence of bits from a C-style string in C?

Tags: c, hash

I need to obtain a sequence of bits from a `char*` fixed length C-style string in C, how can I do it? I need a sequence of bits representing the string, not a particular one. I need to do it strictly in C not in C++.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: Are your bits encoded like this (for example): `"1100101011111110"` or `{0xCA, 0xFE}`

Comment: Yeah, so things happen quickly on Stack Overflow.  When you ask a question here, you need to stick around for a few minutes and be prepared to answer questions that the community has about your post.

Comment: Especially if the question is complicated or unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple bitmask of only one `1` and scan through the string one byte at a time, starting with `mask = 0x80` (binary `10000000`) and going down to `1` (binary `00000001`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

int main(void) {
    char mystring[N] = "abcd";
    unsigned i;
    unsigned char mask;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        unsigned char c = mystring[i];
        unsigned char mask = 0x80;

        do {
            putchar(c & mask ? '1' : '0');
            mask >>= 1;
        } while (mask > 0);

        putchar(' ');
    }

    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
01100001 01100010 01100011 01100100 00000000
```

Comment: Assuming this is what they're really after.

Comment: I don't understand your result. `"abcd" == {0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x00}`

Comment: I see now, your bits in `Result` are reversed.

Comment: @FiddlingBits yea, my mistake I reverted it :P